# Change color of hyperlink in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, colors, uitextview, hyperlink

Is there a way to change hyperlink color in situations when UITextView and, for example,

```
.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

are used?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

With iOS 7, you can change the hyperlink color using the `linkTextAttributes` property of the `UITextView` class.

For example:

```
aTextView.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
```

The above will result in the link displayed in red color.

Comment: i never found any info on it on stackoverflow, so im just going to add  my 2c here, if you want to make the hyperlinks underlined as well, you can add this attribute `{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(1)}`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. The best, easiest way to pull this off is the Nimbus library for attributed labels. You can color, add phone links, email links, the works. And it is much easier to use than the Three20 library that has it all as well.

[Nimbus framework](http://jverkoey.github.com/nimbus/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this with a `UITextView`. The only way to have control over the hyperlink color would be to use a `UIWebView`, where you could use CSS in a manner similar to [this example](http://www.goldcoastwebdesigns.com/change-hyperlink-color.shtml).